# How to use Validation template without the Validation mechanism?

Tags: wpf, validation

I'm using a control template to show validation errors on each of my controls using the built-in WPF's validation mechanism, and everything works fine. The controlTemplate looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
        </Border>
        <Image Name="imgError" 
               Source="/MyAssembly;component/Images/ValidationIcon.png"
               ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=MyAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I have read that the validation mechanism wraps the validated control up with the control template (the default one or a custom one like above) whenever the control gets an error.

> "When the WPF validation system detects an invalid control it creates
>   and adorner that holds a control (...), inserts a control into it and sets that control
>   template to the content of the Validation.ErrorTemplate attached
>   property.
>
> It positions the adorner above the original control so that the
>   AdornedElementPlaceholder is exactly above the control and that let us
>   easily place the control template content relative to the original
>   control" ([see more](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/05/wpf-adorners-part-3-ndash-adorners-and-validation.aspx))

**How can I perform this same behavior for another functionality? I mean use "MyErrorTemplate" without the WPF's validation system, is it possible?**

Comment: Are you looking for the IDataErrorInfo interface? WPF uses this interface to validate objects. (see here http://japikse.blogspot.fr/2009/07/idataerrorinfo-error-templates-and-wpf.html)

Comment: No i'm not. I want to assign the same validation template to a control without using the validation mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if I understand you correctly you want to have the same validation adorning thing without WPF's validation, right?

The approach then is actually to rebuild the components of WPF's validation system:

1. create a Dependency Property `MyCustomErrorTemplate` to hook up your template to the control
2. create a Dependency Property `HasCustomError` to enable showing the error
3. within `MyCustomErrorTemplate_Changed` hook up to the `HasCustomError_Changed` to enable showing/hiding of your adorner
4. create/copy the TemplatedAdorner Class that is then showing your Template

I recommend you use [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) or [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to look at the following code to get some understanding of what's going on. This isn't actually very complex or hard to understand:

in PresentationFramework.dll:

- System.Windows.Controls.Validation (especially the `private static void ShowValidationAdornerHelper(DependencyObject targetElement, DependencyObject adornerSite, bool show, bool tryAgain)`
- MS.Internal.Controls.TemplatedAdorner (sadly this is internal, so you either have to copy it or use some Reflection on it)

Answer (score 0):

Why not? You can have similar attached properties MyValidation.Errors and HasErrors and fill them with your custom logic. And you can have trigger that replaces ControlTemplate with ErrorTemplate when HasError is true. I think this simple approach will do that you need although i am not quite sure that i exactly understand that you need.

Comment: I'd like to use the template like the validation mechanism does. I'm creating controls on the fly and I cannot use binding, so I'd like to assign a control with an error (validated manually) mark.